# How to execute tcl script from php?

Tags: php, tcl

I need to execute a TCL script from PHP. At the moment I am using the following code

```
<?php 
echo passthru("tclsh83 Testcases/source.tcl ");
?>
```

This is working. But this creates a shell for each call . How do I open a shell and communicate to and fro from the TCL script . Any pointers will be appreciated .

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: I got to know the way to pass values from php script to TCL script  

passthru("tclsh83 Testcases/source.tcl $arg1 $arg2 "); // command line arguments 

Is  there a better way to execute the TCL script ? 
Thanks ,
Mithun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lots of data to send to the tcl script, you could open read and write pipes with `proc_open()`.  Then, in the tcl script, use `gets stdin varname` to read a line from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

> I got to know the way to pass values from php script to TCL script passthru("tclsh83 Testcases/source.tcl $arg1 $arg2 "); // command line arguments Is there a better way to execute the TCL script ? Thanks , Mithun

So what's wrong about this way? It is the best way if you will always be passing only 2 parameters and they will be from a trusted source. If not, you can have an array of parameters, escape them using escapeshellarg(), join() them and put the result into the command string. For example:

```
$params = array( /* <...> */ );
echo passthru('tclsh83 Testcases/source.tcl ' .
              join(' ', array_map('escapeshellarg', $params)));
```